# Android: Volley Error response 404

Tags: android, android-volley

Hi I am developing one android application in that I wanna user to login in into the application and during the login I will save all the data from the server by using Shared Preference. I but its just showing the Bad url error and error 404. I don't know what it is. And my code is.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

private EditText userNameET, userPassET;
private Button loginBtn;
private String userType = "";//Created by Ranjani
private String statusinfo="";
private String url = "";
private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private String carAssigningStatus,customerAssigningStatus,driverAssigningStatus;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    userNameET=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.userNameId);
    userPassET=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordId);

    loginBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtnId);
    loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String userNameString = userNameET.getText().toString();
            String userPassString = userPassET.getText().toString();

            if(userNameString == "")
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Username", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                if(userPassString == "")
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else
                {
                    url = "http://www.imaginetventures.net/sample/goodmorning/rest/?type=login&username="+ userNameString+"&password="+userPassString;


                    //Getting information from the webserver
                    GetInfofromserver();
                }
        }
    });
}

private void showpDialog() {
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hidepDialog() {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}
protected void GetInfofromserver() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    showpDialog();

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
            url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

            try {

                        JSONObject logObj = response.getJSONObject("login");

                        JSONArray jArraystatus = logObj
                                .getJSONArray("status");

                        // For Getting Status
                        for (int i = 0; i < jArraystatus.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject status = jArraystatus
                                    .getJSONObject(i);
                            statusinfo = status.getString("user_status");

                            if (statusinfo.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Username / Password does not match",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }
                        }

                        if (statusinfo.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {

                            JSONArray jArraytype = logObj
                                    .getJSONArray("type");
                            JSONArray jArraydriver = logObj
                                    .getJSONArray("driver");
                            JSONArray jcustomerArray = logObj
                                    .getJSONArray("customer");
                            JSONArray jcarArray = logObj
                                    .getJSONArray("car");

                            // For Getting Usertype Info
                            for (int i = 0; i < jArraytype.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject type = jArraytype
                                        .getJSONObject(i);

                                userType = type.getString("user_type");

                                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(
                                        "MyPreferences", 0);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings
                                        .edit();
                                editor.putString("Login_userType", userType);
                                editor.putString("login_Shift_Status", "no");
                                editor.commit();

                                // Log.d("*****===== ", "> " +userType);
                            }

                            switch (userType) {
                            case "driver": {
                                for (int i = 0; i < jArraydriver.length(); i++) {



                                    JSONObject driver = jArraydriver.getJSONObject(i);
                                    if(driver.has("user_id"))
                                    {
                                    String user_Id = driver
                                            .getString("user_id");
                                    String name = driver.getString("name");
                                    String phone = driver
                                            .getString("phone");
                                    String photo = driver
                                            .getString("photo");
                                    String points = driver
                                            .getString("points");

                                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(
                                            "MyPreferences", 0);
                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings
                                            .edit();
                                    editor.putString("driver_user_id",
                                            user_Id);
                                    editor.putString("driver_name", name);
                                    editor.putString("driver_phone", phone);
                                    editor.putString("driver_photo", photo);
                                    editor.putString("driver_points",
                                            points);
                                    // editor.putString("driver_login_status",
                                    // login_status);
                                    editor.commit();
                                    }
                                }
                                for(int inc=0;inc<jcustomerArray.length();inc++)
                                {

                                    JSONObject customer=jcustomerArray.getJSONObject(inc);

                                    if( customer.has("assign_status"))
                                            {
                                                customerAssigningStatus=customer.getString("assign_status");
                                                if(customerAssigningStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
                                                {
                                                JSONObject getcustomer=jcustomerArray.getJSONObject(inc-1);

                                                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", 0);
                                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                                                    String user_Id = getcustomer.getString("user_id");
                                                    String name = getcustomer.getString("name");
                                                    //String gender = c1.getString("gender");
                                                    //String company = c1.getString("company");
                                                    String email = getcustomer.getString("email");
                                                    //String address = c1.getString("address");
                                                    String phone = getcustomer.getString("phone");
                                                    String photo = getcustomer.getString("photo");
                                                    editor.putString("customerAssigningStatus",customerAssigningStatus );
                                                    editor.putString("customer_user_id", user_Id);
                                                    editor.putString("customer_name", name);
                                                    //editor.putString("customer_gender", gender);
                                                    //editor.putString("customer_company", company);
                                                    editor.putString("customer_email", email);
                                                    //editor.putString("customer_address", address);
                                                    editor.putString("customer_phone", phone);
                                                    editor.putString("customer_photo", photo);

                                                    editor.commit();
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", 0);
                                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                                                    editor.putString("customerAssigningStatus",customerAssigningStatus );
                                                    editor.commit();
                                                }
                                            }
                                            }


                                //To Check whether the car have been assigned or not
                                for(int inc=0;inc<jcarArray.length();inc++)
                                {
                                    JSONObject car=jcarArray.getJSONObject(inc);

                                    if( car.has("assign_status"))
                                            {
                                                carAssigningStatus=car.getString("assign_status");

                                                if(carAssigningStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
                                                {
                                                JSONObject getcar=jcarArray.getJSONObject(inc-1);


                                                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", 0);
                                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();



                                                    String carId = getcar.getString("car_id");
                                                    String name = getcar.getString("car_make");
                                                    String model = getcar.getString("car_model");

                                                    String car_type = getcar.getString("car_type");
                                                    String color = getcar.getString("color");
                                                    String car_reg_no = getcar.getString("car_reg_no");
                                                    String model_year = getcar.getString("model_year");
                                                    String photo = getcar.getString("photo");
                                                    String mileage = getcar.getString("mileage");
                                                    Log.d("mileage ===== ",""); 

                                                    editor.putString("carAssigningStatus",carAssigningStatus );
                                                    editor.putString("car_user_id", carId);
                                                    editor.putString("car_name", name);
                                                    editor.putString("car_model", model);
                                                    editor.putString("car_car_type", car_type);
                                                    editor.putString("car_color", color);
                                                    editor.putString("car_car_reg_no", car_reg_no);
                                                    editor.putString("car_model_year", model_year);
                                                    editor.putString("car_photo", photo);
                                                    editor.putString("car_mileage", mileage);
                                                    editor.commit();
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", 0);
                                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                                                    editor.putString("carAssigningStatus",carAssigningStatus );
                                                    editor.commit();
                                                }
                                            }
                                            }




                                break;
                            }

                            case "customer":

                            {
                                for (int i = 0; i < jcustomerArray.length(); i++) {


                                    JSONObject customer = jcustomerArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    if(customer.has("user_id"))
                                    {

                                    String user_Id = customer.getString("user_id");
                                    String name = customer.getString("name");
                                    //String gender = c1.getString("gender");
                                    //String company = c1.getString("company");
                                    String email = customer.getString("email");
                                    //String address = c1.getString("address");
                                    String phone = customer.getString("phone");
                                    String photo = customer.getString("photo");

                                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", 0);
                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

                                    editor.putString("customer_user_id", user_Id);
                                    editor.putString("customer_name", name);
                                    //editor.putString("customer_gender", gender);
                                    //editor.putString("customer_company", company);
                                    editor.putString("customer_email", email);
                                    //editor.putString("customer_address", address);
                                    editor.putString("customer_phone", phone);
                                    editor.putString("customer_photo", photo);

                                    editor.commit();
                                }
                                }
                                for(int inc=0;inc<jArraydriver.length();inc++)
                                {

                                    JSONObject driver=jArraydriver.getJSONObject(inc);

                                    if( driver.has("assign_status"))
                                            {
                                                driverAssigningStatus=driver.getString("assign_status");
                                                if(driverAssigningStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
                                                {
                                                JSONObject getdriver=jArraydriver.getJSONObject(inc-1);

                                                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", 0);
                                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                                                String user_Id = getdriver.getString("user_id");
                                                String name = getdriver.getString("name");
                                                //String gender = c1.getString("gender");
                                                //String company = c1.getString("company");
                                                String email = getdriver.getString("email");
                                                //String address = c1.getString("address");
                                                String phone = getdriver.getString("phone");
                                                String photo = getdriver.getString("photo");
                                                String points=getdriver.getString("points");
                                                String address=getdriver.getString("address");
                                                editor.putString("driverAssigningStatus",driverAssigningStatus );
                                                editor.putString("driver_user_id", user_Id);
                                                editor.putString("driver_name", name);

                                                editor.putString("driver_email", email);
                                                //editor.putString("customer_address", address);
                                                editor.putString("driver_phone", phone);
                                                editor.putString("driver_photo", photo);
                                                editor.putString("driver_address", address);
                                                editor.putString("driver_points", points);

                                                    editor.commit();
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", 0);
                                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                                                    editor.putString("driverAssigningStatus",driverAssigningStatus );
                                                    editor.commit();
                                                }
                                            }
                                            }


                                //To Check whether the car have been assigned or not
                                for(int inc=0;inc<jcarArray.length();inc++)
                                {
                                    JSONObject car=jcarArray.getJSONObject(inc);

                                    if( car.has("assign_status"))
                                            {
                                                carAssigningStatus=car.getString("assign_status");

                                                if(carAssigningStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
                                                {
                                                JSONObject getcar=jcarArray.getJSONObject(inc-1);


                                                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", 0);
                                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();



                                                    String carId = getcar.getString("car_id");
                                                    String name = getcar.getString("car_make");
                                                    String model = getcar.getString("car_model");

                                                    String car_type = getcar.getString("car_type");
                                                    String color = getcar.getString("color");
                                                    String car_reg_no = getcar.getString("car_reg_no");
                                                    String model_year = getcar.getString("model_year");
                                                    String photo = getcar.getString("photo");
                                                    String mileage = getcar.getString("mileage");
                                                    Log.d("mileage ===== ",""); 

                                                    editor.putString("carAssigningStatus",carAssigningStatus );
                                                    editor.putString("car_user_id", carId);
                                                    editor.putString("car_name", name);
                                                    editor.putString("car_model", model);
                                                    editor.putString("car_car_type", car_type);
                                                    editor.putString("car_color", color);
                                                    editor.putString("car_car_reg_no", car_reg_no);
                                                    editor.putString("car_model_year", model_year);
                                                    editor.putString("car_photo", photo);
                                                    editor.putString("car_mileage", mileage);
                                                    editor.commit();
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", 0);
                                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                                                    editor.putString("carAssigningStatus",carAssigningStatus );
                                                    editor.commit();
                                                }
                                            }
                                            }

                                break;
                            }

                            default:
                                break;
                            }
                            SharedPreferences settings1 = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", 0);
                            String strValue1 = settings1.getString("car_mileage",null);

                            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", 0);
                            String strValue = settings.getString("Login_userType",null);


                            if(TextUtils.equals(strValue, "customer")) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ClientTabMainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                            } else if (TextUtils.equals(strValue, "driver")) {

                                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityDriverShiftView.class);
                                startActivity(i);

                            }

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            hidepDialog();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // hide the progress dialog
            hidepDialog();
        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
}
}
```

and the errors are

```
03-02 12:09:33.212: E/Volley(23357): [21267] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for http://www.imaginetventures.net/sample/goodmorning/rest/?type=login&username=davidraja&password=123456
03-02 12:09:33.222: D/Volley(23357): [1] 3.onErrorResponse: MainActivity
```

Note: I wrote this code when for another url, but now the url has been changed and the old one was not in use. But the JSON data are same like previous but I don't know why its not working.

Comment: I wrote this code when for another url, but now the url has been changed and the old one was not in use ? URL you mentioned in error works fine

Comment: yeah I checked the URL in http://jsonlint.com/ and its working fine. But I don't know why I am getting this errors.

Comment: It may help you... https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009EEKIA2